# Submission status of the journal "Advanced Science" from Wiley

Tags: publications, peer-review, paper-submission

I have submitted a manuscript to the journal *Advanced Science* and the manuscript status has been Under Consideration for three weeks. Could anyone having experience in submitting to this journal let me know if the status changes to Under Review if the manuscript is sent out for peer review or does it remain Under Consideration till the review is complete?

Does this mean the paper is still with the editor or associate editor? Is it advisable to contact the editor if the status does not change for another week?

Comment: It does provide a general idea, but I am specifically interested in the process of *Advanced Science*, preferably the experience of someone already submitted to this journal.

Comment: Sorry, our policy is not to take the N*M different permutations of "What does status N at journal M mean?" Even when we have taken such questions in the past, the answer was almost always "hard to say, ask them...or better yet, just wait and they'll be in touch."